# Translate an SQL query into LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm struggling to translate the following SQL query into LINQ.
The outcome column is in type (`varchar`) in the database and I want to cast that into `float`/`double` with LINQ.

```
SELECT TOP 10 CAST(Outcome AS float) AS Max_Outcomes
FROM GameState
where GameId = 1000
ORDER BY Max_Outcomes DESC
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Imo the error, and your attempt would have been usefull. It's a dupe of either "SQL top linq" , "sql order by in linq", or "sql cast ef float". Note that those are not title of real question it's barely keywords used to find hundred of dupe target. Basically I think that something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939961/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828974/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var result = _yourDbContext.GameState
             .Where(c => c.GameId == 1000).AsEnumerable()
             .Select(c => new { Max_Outcomes = (float)c.Outcome })
             .OrderByDescending(c=> c.Max_Outcomes).Take(10).Tolist()
```

Comment: you can't do casting because entity framework will not understand it. also max_outcomes doesn't exist in this context. that's where I am having the problem.

Comment: @Artavazd See my updated answer. Regarding EF to understand cast, you can use `AsEnumerable()`, and for `Max_Outcomes` you can use anonymous type like my updated answer.

Comment: ah, we can do ordering after the selection. it works that way.